# How do I intersect one hash's keys with another and filter out the matching values?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I got this from the Rails doc:

```
{1 => 2}.diff(1 => 2)         # => {}
{1 => 2}.diff(1 => 3)         # => {1 => 2}
{}.diff(1 => 2)               # => {1 => 2}
{1 => 2, 3 => 4}.diff(1 => 2) # => {3 => 4}
```

This is almost perfect but I don't want values that are in the hash passed as parameter and not in the calling hash.

What I want:

```
{}.diff(1 => 2) # => {}
{a: 1}.diff({a: 1, b: 2}) # => {} instead of {:b => 2}
```

Also, it must be as efficient as possible. For instance, I don't want to go over the second hash and check that each key that's inside doesn't appear in the first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source is helpful here.

```
def diff(h2)
  dup.delete_if { |k, v| h2[k] == v }.merge!(h2.dup.delete_if { |k, v| has_key?(k) })
end
```

Which iterates over every entry in the hash. I'm assuming you don't want to add an unnecessary iteration. So it's easier than the above

```
def my_diff(h2)
  dup.delete_if { |k, v| h2[k] == v }
end
```

Comment: Heh, I was stuck trying to use diff at any cost. Didn't think to gp with a different approach.

Comment: `my_diff` doesn't work if h2 contains keys that h doesn't - `{a: 1, b: 2}.my_diff(a: 2) => {:a=>1, :b=>2}`. The block should be `h2[k] == v || !h2.key?(k)`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald this is actually the desired behavior, since both keys of `{a: 1, b: 2}` are not the same as `{a: 2}`. I want all elements of the calling hash that are different (key and value) than the second hash. The other way around mustn't work!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy:

```
a.select {|k, v| b.key?(k) && b[k] != v }
```

This is O(n), since both `key?` and `Hash#[]` are both O(1).